# form select option dynamic attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to make Select name with option value, to select a specific value or index. the data where comes from db in a value "{{design}}". 
I do get the value currectly, but I dont manage to set "selected" on the currect option value.
here is the code:

```
console.log("{{design}}");
$(document).ready(function () {
       var options = $('select').children('option');
    var size =    $('select').children('option').length;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if ( options[i].innerHTML==="{{design}}")
        {
            options.selectedIndex=i;
        }
    }
});
```

the html is :

```
      <select name="design" required id="design"  >
                <option value="1">flowers</option>
                <option value="2">classic</option>
                <option value="3">roses</option>
            </select>
```

I need to make to currect {{design}} value, lets say it's 2, so it will be  `<option value="2" selected>classic</option`>`

thanks!

### SOLVED

Hi, found the solution to the issue, if anyone eles goes into trouble.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var options =      $('select').children('option');
        var size =    $('select').children('option').length;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if ( $('select').children('option')[i].value === "{{design}}")
            {

                 $('select').children('option')[i].selected=true;
            }
        }
    });
```

the currect way is to find the right option value and then-> [i].selected=true

goodluck

Comment: if you are comparing with value use options[i].value or if you are checking against text you can use innerHTML .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you are on the right path just taking a minor detour. Try this:

```
if ( options[i].innerHTML==="{{design}}")
    {
        options.attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
```

The example of .each() usage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option').each(function(i){
        if( i.value === "{{design}}"){
            $(this).attr('selected','selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe options[i].attr('selected', 'selected'); ?

Comment: Actually, you might wanna take a look at http://api.jquery.com/each/ - .each() scrolls through all of the selected elements, when the current element matches your specifications, then .attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: I just now saw your other recommendtion, looks great but found what I wrote in "solved"
seems just about the right also, thanks!

Comment: Alright, good job. Just figured I'd throw that in there, it would make stuff more easy to read and handle, if you wanna consider changing to it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selectedvalue=2; //option with value 2 should be selected
$("#design option[value=selectedvalue]").attr("selected","selected");
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: found the right solution for my problem, editing the question, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option').each(function(i){
       //if this option contains the word "{{design}}" Then this is selected
        if( $(this).html().indexOf("{{design}}") != -1)
            $(this).attr('selected',true);
    });
});
```